# Retrieving project version from csproj in Azure Pipeline .NET Core CLI task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, yaml, azure-artifacts

I have the following tasks in my yaml file in Azure DevOps
It publishes my console application and zip it in a file

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/MyApp.csproj'
    arguments: '-r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=True --self-contained true -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

I set the project version directly on the project file in Visual Studio when I make any changes.
Now I'm trying to get that version when I am publishing the project in AzureDevOps and customise the file name, lets say for a project version 1.2.1 the archived file output of the publish in azure should be MyApp-v1.2.1.zip
Currently it only output file as MyApp.zip

Not sure if even my approach towards versioning is correct, so appreciate any input!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need and I did it as below. In my case it is archived and published differently but I think you get the main idea.

```yaml
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Get version number'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
         $VERSION=([xml](Get-Content **\MyApp.csproj)).Project.PropertyGroup.Version
         Write-Host("##vso[task.setvariable variable=VERSION]$VERSION")
    
    ... // heare I archive the built files.
    
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyApp_$(VERSION).zip'
        artifact: 'MyApp_$(VERSION)'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

In the first powershell task I get the version number from the project file and set it to a variable called `VERSION`. I learned it from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56039297/275940 answer which
has done the same for maven project.

In the second task I used the variable to make correct file path.